# Number of lightest paths from single source vertex

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, bellman-ford

Assume I have a directed, weighted graph with positive or negative weights, (with no zero or negative weighted loops).
The graph is Bellman-Ford analized, meaning each vertex holds the data of the lightest path to it from the source vertex, and its predecessor in the lightest path.
What is the most efficient way to store the number of different shortest paths from the source to each vertex?
I am willing to make it in linear time - O(V+E) if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it pretty efficiently if you have *no negative edges* as well.

Let the shortest path to node `v` be denoted as `D(v)`

sort vertices by distances - O(VlogV)

Denote `P(v)` - number of paths leading from the source to `v`.

Now, you can use DP to solve this relation (from first to last):

```
P(source) = 1
P(v) = sum { P(u) | (u,v) is an edge and D(u) + w(u,v) = D(v) }
```

Complexity of the algorithm is `O(VlogV + E)`

**Correctness proof**: by induction (guidelines):

Base clause for source, there is a single path (the empty path).

let us assume P(v) is correct for every `v` such that `D(v) < D(u)`.

For every shortest path that ends with `u`, it must go through one of the vertices such that `D(v) < D(u)`. Given a shortest path `source->...->v->u`, the path is counted in `P(v)`. In addition, it is not counted for any other `P(v')`, so it is counted exactly once in `sum { P(u) | (u,v) is an edge and D(u) + w(u,v) = D(v) }`.

In addition, for any path which is not shortest path, from induction hypothesis, it is not counted for any `v` such that `D(v)<D(u)`, so the path must be generated in the last step, but the restriction `(u,v) is an edge and D(u) + w(u,v) = D(v)` is preventing it, so we do not count any non-shortest path.

**QED**

Comment: But as I understood it, the OP does have negative edges, doesn't he?